# Disable Specified Days. How to show date in datepicker only if this date is "startdate + 5 days" AND "enddate - 14 days"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show date in datepicker jQuery UI (in #id_erinnerung_am field) only if this date is in "startdate + 5 days" AND "enddate - 14 days". Only these date, the other disable.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".vDateField" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
});
```

My Script Js:

```
TIME_UNITS = {
    '1': 'days',
    '2': 'months',
    '3': 'years'
}

function get_date_from_string(strDate) {
    var dateParts = strDate.split('.');
    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    return date;
}

function recalculate_deadline() {
    var = startdate = $('#id_laufzeit_von').val(); #START DATE
    var enddate = $('#id_laufzeit_bis').val();     #ENDDATE
    if (!enddate) {
        return;
    }
    enddate = moment(new get_date_from_string(enddate));
    // get cancelling period and unit
    var timeunit_cancelling = TIME_UNITS[$('#id_kuendigungsfrist_type').val()];
    var cancelling_deadline = $('#id_kuendigungsfrist').val();

    if (!cancelling_deadline) {
        return;
    }
    cancelling_deadline = parseInt(cancelling_deadline, 10);
    enddate.subtract(timeunit_cancelling, cancelling_deadline);

    // show date in input field
    var $cancel_until = $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis');
    $cancel_until.val(enddate.format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
    $cancel_until.change();
}

function check_reminder_date() {
    var $reminder_date = $('#id_erinnerung_am');
    var $cancel_until = $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis');
    reminder_date = $reminder_date.val();

    cancel_until = $cancel_until.val();
    if (!cancel_until) {
        return;
    }

    cancel_until = get_date_from_string(cancel_until);

    // If reminder_date is set, check that it is earlier than cancelling date
    if (reminder_date) {

        reminder_date = get_date_from_string(reminder_date);

        if (reminder_date <= cancel_until) {
            // everything is fine, just return
            return;
        }
    }
    // correct or set date for reminder
    reminder_date = moment(cancel_until);

    reminder_date.subtract('months', 1);
    $reminder_date.val(reminder_date.format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
    $reminder_date;
    //alert(reminder_date); //Fri Mar 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
    $reminder_date.datepicker(setValue(reminder_date));

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_laufzeit_bis').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist').change(recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist_type').change(recalculate_deadline);

    $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis').change(check_reminder_date);
    $('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker('hide').on(check_reminder_date);

});
```

How to do it? I'm newbie in Java Script

Comment: var = startdate = $('#id_laufzeit_von').val(); #START DATE i think you have i typo in this line.

Comment: #START DATE and this is not valid way of adding comments //START DATE is valid.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a problem. I need disable specified Days in datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the api and the examples. You can restrict the dates and disable some dates

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

Comment: It work only here: `$( ".vDateField" )` but in `$('#id_erinnerung_am')` not

Comment: are they both `$('#id_erinnerung_am')` and `$( ".vDateField" )` not text fields?